# Accessing Delta Lake Table in Databricks via Spark in MLflow project

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, mlflow

I am currently accessing deltalake table from databricks notebook using spark. However now I need to access delta tables from MLflow project. MLflow spark api only allows logging and loading of SparkML models. Any idea on how can I accomplish this?

Currently I am trying to access spark via this code in MLflow project:

```py
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession._instantiatedSession
if spark is None:
  # NB: If there is no existing Spark context, create a new local one.
  # NB: We're disabling caching on the new context since we do not need it and we want to
  # avoid overwriting cache of underlying Spark cluster when executed on a Spark Worker
  # (e.g. as part of spark_udf).
  spark = ( pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder \
   .config("spark.python.worker.reuse", True)
   .config("spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled", False)
   # In Spark 3.1 and above, we need to set this conf explicitly to enable creating
   # a SparkSession on the workers
   .config("spark.executor.allowSparkContext", "true")
   .master("local[*]")
   .appName("MLflow Project")
   .getOrCreate()
  )
```

But I am getting this error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Why do you need o access delta lake from a model?

Comment: not from a model. I meant, how can I access delta lake table from mlflow project? right now I am accessing it in databricks notebook via spark.table() without initiation any spark instance because databricks notebook does this itself. If I need to access a deltalake table that resides in databricks how can I access it in apart from databricks notebook?

Answer (score 1):

It should be done the same way as for normal Spark projects that doesn't run in Notebooks:

- Add dependencies to `spark-submit` or `pyspark`, you need to install `delta-spark` package to use code completion, etc. (`--conf` could be set from code itself, see next step):

```sh
pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.1.0 \
  --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
  --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

- create a `SparkSession` object and use it:

```py
import pyspark
from delta import *

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
  .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
  .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

These steps are covered in the [Quickstart guide](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#set-up-apache-spark-with-delta-lake) included into Delta documentation.

If data resides on Azure Data Lake Storage, or AWS S3, or GCP, you may need to add additional packages & configurations, but that's also covered in documentation.

Comment: Still getting the same error : py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.

Comment: Look into lines starting with “Caused by”

Comment: When I added the code you advised, it gave me an error to set master url. When I set the master url like this .master("local[*]"). It gave me this error py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.

Comment: I am using a single node cluster. Is that causing this problem? because the notebooks are attached to that cluster

Comment: No. It shouldn’t…

Answer (score 1):

Running MLflow projects within Databricks notebooks (e.g., against an existing interactive cluster from within a notebook attached to that cluster) isn’t currently well-supported for several reasons (including e.g., the lack of auth propagation to the subprocess created to run the project).